# SQL - Working Out Time 'Period'

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am compiling a report from 2 different data sources. The request is that I provide an hourly breakdown of sales, quotes and calls so I can provide the call to quote rate etc.

The telephone data comes in the format of 'hourly' like below:

```
Date                    Start         Offered         Answered
----------------------- ------------- ------------------------------
2016-05-09 00:00:00.000 08:00         0             0
2016-05-09 00:00:00.000 09:00         7             5
2016-05-09 00:00:00.000 10:00         7             7
2016-05-09 00:00:00.000 11:00         7             6
2016-05-09 00:00:00.000 12:00         10            10
2016-05-09 00:00:00.000 13:00         5             5
2016-05-09 00:00:00.000 14:00         2             2
2016-05-09 00:00:00.000 15:00         2             2
2016-05-09 00:00:00.000 16:00         7             7
2016-05-09 00:00:00.000 17:00         7             7
2016-05-09 00:00:00.000 18:00         0             0
2016-05-09 00:00:00.000 19:00         0             0
```

This suits me down to the ground so I can show the data hourly i.e. between 08:00 and 09:00 there were no calls offer and subsequently none answered.

Now the difference here is the Quote/Sales system provides the time as such 0932, 1001 etc.

What would be the best way to put these Quotes/Sales into the appropriate 'hourly' pots.

I.e. 0932 should essentially be 09:00 as a time below and 1001 should be 10:00.

Is the best way to accomplish this just CASE statements based on the first 2 digits of the time i.e.

```
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING([QuoteTime],1,2) = 09 THEN '0900' END
```

I figure I could do it this way but it would be 'cumbersome' and quite a performance hit on a number of rows.

Thoughts?

Comment: How is date provided in Quote/Sales system?

Comment: You'll take a performance hit in any case because some kind of conversion will be involved. You can definitely use a *shorter* expression -- `STUFF([QuoteTime], 3, 0, ':')` -- but the important thing is that whatever things you join or group on should have the same type, which should be the type of the underlying table with the most rows.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek - It is provided as 21/05/2016 as a varchar.

Comment: `STUFF([QuoteTime], 3, 2, ':00')`, sorry. Missed the fact that we had to round down to whole hours.

Comment: @JeroenMostert that is insane that has accomplished what 8/9 CASE statements did, what exactly is that doing? For my own understanding.

Comment: [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188043) is a weird function that's the Swiss army knife of T-SQL string processing -- it deletes a specific part of a string, then inserts another. It can be used to remove, substitute or insert substrings depending on how it's called.